# command to select faces based on a uv shell in Maya

Tags: python, select, polygon, maya, face

I am trying to figure out a command / code to be able to select all faces on a given UV Shell on a polygon. I have tried various flags of polySelect and related commands but couldn't get what I wanted. Any help on this ?

I tried this but it selects all faces of the object. But I need to select faces only upto the UV Shell that it is a part of.

`cmds.polySelect('objName', ets=200)`